# Problem adding MP3 attachments to a jPlayer playlist

Tags: jquery, javascript, attachments, audio

I'm trying to get a post's mp3 attachments working with the jplayer plugin (with playlist addon). I have it working for a set number of attachments, but am failing to find a dynamic solution for any number of attachments.

Currently, the mp3 attachment urls and titles are fetched and added as attributes to the '.jp-playlist' div. This is so the data can be accessed via jquery to set up a playlist for the jplayer. (this may not be the most elegant solution, so any feedback on a better method appreciated)

Code to setup jPlayer in single.php:

```
<div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
<div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-audio">
  <div class="jp-type-playlist">
    <div class="jp-gui jp-interface">
      <ul class="jp-controls">
        <li><a href="#" class="jp-previous" tabindex="1">previous</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="jp-next" tabindex="1">next</a></li>
      </ul>                         
    </div>
    <div class="jp-playlist" data-track-1="exampleurl1.mp3" data-title-1="Track 1" data-track-2="exampleurl2.mp3" data-title-2="Track 2" data-track-3="exampleurl3.mp3" data-title-3="Track 3" >
      <ul>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </div> <!-- .jp-playlist -->
  </div> <!-- .jp-type-playlist -->
</div> <!-- #jp_container_1 -->
```

jQuery code to initialise jPlayer and set up the playlist:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist({
    jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
    }, [
      { 
        title: $(".jp-playlist").attr("data-title-1"), 
        mp3: $(".jp-playlist").attr("data-track-1") 
      },
      { 
        title: $(".jp-playlist").attr("data-title-2"), 
        mp3: $(".jp-playlist").attr("data-track-2") 
      },
      { 
        title: $(".jp-playlist").attr("data-title-3"), 
        mp3: $(".jp-playlist").attr("data-track-3") 
      }
    ], {
    swfPath: "Jplayer.swf",
    supplied: "mp3"
  });
});
```

This works fine if there are three mp3 attachments, but I need to make it adaptable for any number of attachments. I guess the solution is to have a javascript loop to get all the data-track/title attributes, and outputting them into an array for the playlist object, but I'm not having much success. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) for passing php data to javascript. A pseudo-code example:

```
$tracks = array();

foreach( $mp3_attachments as $mp3_attachment ):
    $tracks[] = array(
        'mp3' => $mp3_attachment['filename'],
        'title' => $mp3_attachment['title']
    );
endforeach;

$wpa_track_data = array( 'tracks' => $tracks );

wp_enqueue_script( 'wpa_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/yourscript.js' );
wp_localize_script( 'wpa_script', 'wpa_data', $wpa_track_data );
```

Then in your js `wpa_data.tracks` will contain your array of mp3s and titles.

Comment: Thanks Milo. I had tried using wp_localize_script previously, but hadn't managed to get it to work and assumed it was because it doesn't support multi-dimensional arrays. However, you inspired me to give it another go and IT WORKS NOW!!!